# Navigate does not redirecting to the specified path in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redirect, navigation

I am trying to redirect to another router when the user clicks a specified button (named Navigate in this case) in a class-based component (named Counter). I am using `<Navigate />` for that. It doesn't redirect to the page I specified to redirect to (path='/' for the homepage). In addition, I don't get any errors. Someone, please tell me the best way to use the `<Navigate />`.

For reference, the code is:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Navigate} from 'react-router-dom'

class Counter extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
           
        }

        this.navigate = this.navigate.bind(this)
    }
    
    navigate(e){
        return <Navigate to="/" />
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className='text-center'>
                <h1>Hello there, this is a counter app</h1>
                <button onClick={this.navigate} >Navigate</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Counter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this. In your component navigate function cannot return Navigation. There are other methods for switching routes programmatically. Read this https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Navigate} from 'react-router-dom'

class Counter extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
           dashboard: false,
        }

        this.navigate = this.navigate.bind(this)
    }
    
    navigate(e){
        this.setState({dashboard:true})
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className='text-center'>
                {this.state.dashboard && (
                    <Navigate to="/dashboard" replace={true} />
                )}
                <h1>Hello there, this is a counter app {this.state.dashboard && <span>dashboard</span>}</h1>
                <button onClick={this.navigate} >Navigate</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Counter
```